# Birkat HaMazon with everyone in mind?

Tags: halacha, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, bentching

I have been by a couple Sepharadi households for Shabbat and when it was time for Birkat HaMazon the head of the household alone would read the entire thing outloud noting they would have everyone at the meal in mind, rather than everyone reading themselves.

What is the Halacha surrounding this? Does it strictly apply to Sephardi posek? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is known as a Zimmun and occurs when a group (subject to various details) eats bread together. When there is a Zimmun, the leader recites the entire Birkat HaMazon aloud on the group's behalf and everyone else listens with the intent to fulfill their obligation and replies Amen at the relevant places.

If one is unsure of his ability to pay attention to the leader the whole time (this is common), he should recite in an undertone along with the leader but be careful to get a few words ahead of the leader at points where an Amen should be said in order that the listener can still respond Amen to the leader. ([Shulchan Aruch OC 183:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=171))

Comment: And I am one of the only people I know who actually bother to say the entire thing out loud when I am asked to lead (and therefore I hate being asked to lead). +1

Comment: @Yez I say it all aloud as well. With a niggun. So we're in the same boat...

Comment: "this is common" is an understatement and would imo be better edited to "this is by far the most common occurrence".

Comment: @msh I don't know that I agree.

Comment: @DoubleAA You don't agree that it is by far the most common occurrence for people to not be able to pay attention, or that it is by far the most common for people to be unsure of their ability to pay attention? I have never been at a single meal where anyone ever sat and silently listened to the leader. I suppose they could all be ignorant and not realize that if they have the ability to pay attention they should, but the result that they recite along in an undertone seems to be virtually universal.

Comment: @Yez I don't share your experience in your second sentence but I do share your supposition in your last sentence and your observation of the unfortunate mistaken result. In places like a Yeshiva there's essentially no reason to assume people can't listen along. Rule of thumb: if you can host Torah reading on Shabbat in that group without people talking to each other, then they can listen through four blessings after bread. Sure in lots of places there's talking through all of Davening and there listening for Zimmun is clearly a bad idea, but it's not like it's beyond human capabilities anymore

Comment: @Yez Even if you think I'm bring a bit extreme (which I tend to agree with), know there are serious opinions that you _have_ to do the silent listening till at least Hazan Et HaKol for Ashkenazim (to count as a Zimmun). That is no less doable than listening to Kiddush Friday night and in home settings at least can certainly be implemented, with mumbling along commencing with 'Nodeh'.